# about run shell command in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

I have a controller which call shell command.
In my local, The action method will wait shell run until it finished.

But when it runs in production server, The rails will not wait shell command run finished,The action method will runs very quickly.

anyone can tell me the reason?

Comment: Include the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

sorry. It's call script command will cause this problem